# Proof of $E(Y|X,Z)=E(Y|X)$, if $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$

Tags: statistics, independence

$ E(Y|X,Z)=E(Y|X)$, if $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$.

I learned this on an Econometrics lecture but I have a bit of trouble proving this.
I already tried to apply the definition of independence and conditional expectation, like this,

\begin{align}
E(Y|X,Z) &= \sum_{y}yP(Y=y|X=x, Z=z) \\
&=\sum_{y}y \frac{P(Y=y,X=x, Z=z)}{P(X=x, Z=z)}\\
&=\sum_{y}y \frac{P(Z=z)P(Y=y,X=x)}{P(X=x, Z=z)} \\
\end{align}

I don't know how to continue.

Thanks for any tips and suggestions.

Comment: Isn't $P(Y=y|X,Z)=P(Y=y|X)$ since $Y$ and $Z$ are independent?

Comment: @MPW that would hold in general only if $Y$ and $Z$ were conditionally independent given $X$ (which is true here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have reached $\mathsf E(Y|X,Z)~=~\dfrac{\sum_{y} y\,\mathsf P(Z=z)\,\mathsf P(Y=y,X=x)}{\mathsf P(X=x, Z=z)}$

Netx use the Law of Total Probability

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y|X,Z)~&=~\dfrac{\sum_y y\,\mathsf P(Z=z)\mathsf P(Y=y, X=x)}{\sum_y \mathsf P(Y=y, X=x, Z=z)} \\[1ex]&=~ \phantom{\dfrac{\mathsf P(Z=z)\sum_y y\,\mathsf P(Y=y, X=x)}{\mathsf P(Z=z)\sum_y \mathsf P(Y=y, X=x)}}\\[1ex]&=~ \dfrac{\sum_y y\,\mathsf P(Y=y, X=x)}{\mathsf P(X=x)}\end{align}$$

---

Remark: Since $Z$ is independent of $(X,Y)$ jointly, we can assert that $Z$ is independent of $X$ alone. Then $\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x,Z{=}z)~{~=~\mathsf P(X{=}x,Y{=}y,Z{=}z)/\mathsf P(X{=}x,Z{=}z) \\~=~ \mathsf P(X{=}x,Y{=}y)\mathsf P(Z{=}z)/\mathsf P(X{=}x)\mathsf P(Z{=}z) \\~=~ \mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid X{=}x)}$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(Y=y\mid X=x,Z= z) = \frac{P(Y=y,X=x\mid Z=z)}{P(X=x\mid Z = z)} = \frac{P(Y=y,X=x)}{P(X=x)} = P(Y=y\mid X=x)$$ where we used independence of $(X,Y)$ from $Z$ in the second equality and definition of conditional probability in the others.